# Horrible eclipse performance on macbook pro running 10.5.8

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-3.5

I am using eclipse galileo on my macbook pro. After a few minutes it starts dragging really badly, like it takes 8 seconds to open a file. I don't have many files open at all. I already modified the config file to increase ram and all that stuff. Is there something wrong with this version of eclipse, never had it run so poorly on here,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with OS X 10.5.8 and my Eclipse runs great. Start by looking at the heap (Preferences -> General -> Show Heap Status). Next, check the Error Log for errors in your Eclipse platform (Window -> Show View -> Error Log).

This could be a problem with one of your plugins or with the workspace. I would try downloading a clean Eclipse install (you can have as many as you need) and starting a new Workspace. Try importing your projects (do not copy the settings). See if it works better for you.

Make sure you get the Cocoa version.

Comment: +1. Good advices (and nice blog post you mentioned to me in the comments below).

Answer (score 2):

After looking at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204173/eclipse-ide-speed-sluggish-on-snow-leopard-macbook), I would recommend:

- using an optimized eclipse ini (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590))
- replacing in that eclipse.ini `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5` by -**`Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6`** (see this [SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046887/eclipse-3-5-switching-tab-is-very-slow)
- <del>use 64-bit Cocoa andand add to the JVM switches (still in the eclipse.ini) for running in 64 bit on Snow Leopard</del>:

```
    -XX:+UseParallelGC
    -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

(The last point would apply for Snow Leopard -- 10.6.x -- and not Leopard -- 10.6.5 -- as mentioned by [zvikico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823/zvikico), so read his [blog post on the topic](http://blog.zvikico.com/2009/10/installing-eclipse-galileo-on-mac-os-x.html) (and upvote [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399084/horrible-eclipse-performance-on-macbook-pro-running-10-5-8/2399523#2399523) in this thread ;) )

Comment: My experience teaches me that the only difference is that using 64-bit on Leopard consumes more memory and system resources. On Snow Leopard it is the other way around.

Comment: There are reasons for that. I invite you to read the full post here: http://blog.zvikico.com/2009/10/installing-eclipse-galileo-on-mac-os-x.html

Comment: `UseCompressedOops` is enabled by default as of JDK 6u23. http://blog.juma.me.uk/2008/10/14/32-bit-or-64-bit-jvm-how-about-a-hybrid/