# Eclipse 3.5 (Cocoa) slowing down irregularly after some time

Tags: eclipse, macos

I'd like to hear, if anyone else encounters the same problems, and **doesn't** use Google's GWT (2.0) plugins:

Sometimes, my Eclipse 3.5 (Cocoa) slows down after some time of usage (>=30 minutes), so that things like maximizing an editor or moving the splitters becomes unbearably slow (reacting only after several seconds). After an Eclipse restart, everything's fine again.

I'm not running low on memory (neither free RAM, nor memory available to Eclipse - Heap/Stack/PermGenSpace), and my system specs are not too bad.

I know exactly one other person so far, who sees the same problem - but he also uses the GWT plugins. Since these issues appear irregularly, they're hard to track. Before creating an issue on the GWT bug tracker, I'd like to find out, if this also happens for somebody without Google's plugins.

Thanks,

Chris

**Edit:**

I'm running Snow Leopard 10.6.2, Eclipse 3.5 Cocoa 32-bit.

eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.0.1.R35x_v20090707
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=280m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-Xms54m
-Xmx560m
```

Comment: Accepted the answer from VonC until I know, if it resolves the problem.

Comment: did you tweak your eclipse.ini in any way, or do you mean the issue has not yet manifested itself again since 3 days ago?

Comment: I'm playing around with the `XX` options - it hasn't manifested itself since (no matter if I start with the new XX options, or with my old eclipse.ini) - but this problem is so evasive, that I'd expect that. Knowing, that it can also happen for others without the GWT plugins already helps me to know what to look out for a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **[good `eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)** can help.
But as mentioned in "[Horrible eclipse performance on macbook pro running 10.5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399084/horrible-eclipse-performance-on-macbook-pro-running-10-5-8/2399405#2399405)" (which kind of illustrate the fact that performance issue can happen with Galileo *without* `GWT`), it can depend on the OS version (Snow Leopard or Leopard).

Comment: Ok, thanks - do you see any specific problem in my eclipse.ini? BTW, I already used jconsole to connect to Eclipse, and didn't see any memory problem in any memory pool - and there was a maximum of 35 threads (no deadlocks detected).

Comment: @chris_l: your eclipse.ini looks good. Try adding some of the options I have in mine, especially specifying the full path of the VM you use to launch Eclipse (see my eclipse.ini for example).

Comment: Thanks. I checked in About Eclipse->...->Configuration, that I'm running with the correct VM. The other differences between your and my eclipse.ini seem to be mostly about GC. It shouldn't be a memory issue - could the choice of GC options still have an effect? I suspect some issue with SWT's UI thread. I wonder, if this is Cocoa specific.

Comment: @chris_l: no, the difference between a standard JVM and my `eclipse.ini` is that I directly call `jvm.dll`, which avoids an unnecessary `javaw` process. And try adding the `XX` options as well, just to see if an effect can be observed there.

Comment: Ok, I will try it! It may take some time until it happens again (some days it doesn't happen at all, other days, it happens all the time. Must depend somehow on what I'm doing in Eclipse - but I still have no idea what the triggering factor could be.)

Answer (score 0):

I have macbook with osx 10.6.3
Eclipse 3.5.2

I develop gwt 2.0.3 + ext-gwt 2.1.3.

I have noticed that suddenly a part of the project slows down. I mean, while before loading the screen was 2-5 sec in dev mode, suddenly increased to a minute or two (?????).

I remember, that earlier, I have re-installed eclipse, but that did not work (????), and when created a new workspace, and moved the project there, suddenly the slowing was gone.

So, I did the same now also.

I don't know the exact reason / solution. However, under the workspace there is a folder ".metadata/.plugins" in there there are lot's of folders. In the "org.eclipse.core.resources" / ".projects" you have for each project you got in your workspace a folder.

Noticed that when I have copied here the project-folder of the same project, created in other workspace, the slowing was gone.

So, eventually the solution is simple: to delete the project from the workspace, but only from the "Package explorer" - that actually removes the folder belonging to the removed project from the above mentioned folder (".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/"), while keeping the project files at their location (you should make a backup of it just for sure :) ), and than importing it back.

Voila!

It works fine again.